# PHP throwing server errors after Ubuntu ran an unattended-upgrades session - any way to determine the cause?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, domain-name-system, php

We just had an incident on one of our webservers. Several PHP applications run on it and started spitting out the following error message:

`php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`

This message seems to be network/dns related. The server logs clearly indicated that around the time that the first error occurred, Ubuntu started an `unattended-upgrades` session. I will attach the output from `dpkg.log` below.

We use an external database server.

We decided to reboot the webserver, which solved the issue, but the question now is:

**Is there any way that I can find out the underlying cause of this issue so that I can prevent it in the future?**

Output from *unattended-upgrades.log*:

```
2017-03-21 15:01:56,279 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2017-03-21 15:01:56,279 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=xenial', 'o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security']
2017-03-21 15:02:03,365 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libfreetype6 locales multiarch-support
2017-03-21 15:02:03,365 INFO Writing dpkg log to '/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log'
2017-03-21 15:02:12,851 INFO All upgrades installed
```

Output from *dpkg.log*:

```
2017-03-21 15:02:03 startup archives unpack
2017-03-21 15:02:03 upgrade libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:03 status half-configured libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:03 status unpacked libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:03 status half-installed libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-installed libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 upgrade libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-configured libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-installed libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-installed libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 upgrade libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-configured libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status unpacked libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:04 status half-installed libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-installed libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status unpacked libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status unpacked libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 startup packages configure
2017-03-21 15:02:05 configure libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status unpacked libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status unpacked libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-configured libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status installed libc6:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status installed man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:05 startup archives unpack
2017-03-21 15:02:05 upgrade locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-configured locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status unpacked locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:05 status half-installed locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status triggers-pending man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status half-installed locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status unpacked locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status unpacked locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:06 upgrade libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status half-installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status half-installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:06 trigproc man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:06 status half-configured man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed man-db:amd64 2.7.5-1
2017-03-21 15:02:07 startup packages configure
2017-03-21 15:02:07 configure libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 startup archives unpack
2017-03-21 15:02:07 upgrade multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-installed multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-installed multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu5
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 startup packages configure
2017-03-21 15:02:07 configure multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed multiarch-support:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 startup archives unpack
2017-03-21 15:02:07 upgrade libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-installed libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-installed libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:07 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 startup packages configure
2017-03-21 15:02:07 configure libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed libc-dev-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 configure libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status installed libc6-dev:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 configure locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status unpacked locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:07 status half-configured locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status installed locales:all 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:11 configure libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status triggers-pending libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status unpacked libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status half-configured libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status installed libfreetype6:amd64 2.6.1-0.1ubuntu2.1
2017-03-21 15:02:11 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6 <none>
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status half-configured libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:11 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.23-0ubuntu6
2017-03-21 15:02:11 startup packages configure
```

Comment: Same problem here on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04. Unattended upgraded last night : 2017-03-21 03:42:53,570 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev locales multiarch-support Just created a case on ubuntu bug tracker : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

Comment: libc6 is where the getaddrinfo() function lives. The changelog for the package indicates there was a security update to the DNS resolver code: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/2.23-0ubuntu6, so it's pretty likely to have been an issue with the recent libc6 security update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We saw this hit our environment and it happened again 5 hours later. Considering rolling back to an older version of libc6 patch.

Here is the Ubuntu bug for this issue that confirms what we're all seeing: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532

**Update: the issue has since been fixed.**

See comments [#16](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532/comments/16), [#17](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532/comments/17) and [#18](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532/comments/18) in the above report. Updating `libc` should resolve the issue. A reboot is recommended to make sure that any running processes that are running during the update that make use of this library keep functioning the way they should.

Comment: Link to a semi-related issue on StackOverflow has been removed from the answer since it is from 2010 and shows the same error message but with an unrelated cause. For reference, I will add it as a comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661546/php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known