# Apache/PHP unable to resolve hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, php5

This morning for the second day in a row, PHP on my server was unable to resolve the hostname to a IP via `file_get_contents('http://newswebsite.com/feed.rss')`, and `service restart apache2` resolved the issue, but this was never an issue anyway.

There doesn't seem to be any errors in the apache logs. Are there any other places I can check for a misconfiguration or error logging ?

**OS information**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.150519
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

**Apache 2 version**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 15 2016 15:34:04
```

**PHP Version**

```
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 (cli) (built: Feb  9 2017 20:54:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

**IP Configuration**

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.106/27
        gateway xx.xx.xx.97
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface eth0 inet6 static
        address xx:xx:xx:xx::100:1
        netmask 64
        gateway xx::xx:xx:xx:1
        dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost        lo
127.0.1.1       websrvA01
```

**/etc/hostname**

```
websrvA01
```

Comment: The /var/log directory contains all sorts of logs. Some of them may even be relevant.

Comment: Could be related to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/839659/php-throwing-server-errors-after-ubuntu-ran-an-unattended-upgrades-session-any

Comment: how does you /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname look like?

Comment: Added hosts and hostname to my question.

Comment: Apache does not do name resolutions of any kind and you are refering to a PHP function, so why do you look at Apache when you should look to PHP?

Comment: @ezra-s Because restarting apache resolves the issue..

Comment: @Sander in any case, not an apache issue since Apache itself does not do name resolutions at all, but I might have a good tip for you anyways, it has come to my attention  in ubuntu there has been a recent update of libc6 that screws up system name resolution, you may be affected by it. Check [libc6 bug] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733) and [more libc6 bug references] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bug/1674532)